# How do I ask a girl if she's single in German?

Tags: phrase-request

How do I ask a girl if she's single in German? I want to impress her and I don't trust Google Translate.
Google's translation is "Was hast du heute gemacht?".

Comment: *Was hast du heute gemacht?* is German for *What did you do today?* - please [edit] your question to give us the original sentence or context you had in mind.

Comment: Klingt ein bisschen nach _how you doin’?_ (Catchphrase von Joey in der TV-Serie „Friends“)

Answer (score 2):

> Was hast du heute gemacht

literally means "What did you do today?"

I do not know your original query you tried to translate, but if you are anxious to get it wrong, simply ask

> Bist du Single? (Are you single?)

The word *single* is well understood in Germany in the meaning of a person without a partner.

A variation would be:

> Hast du einen Freund? (Do you have a **boy**friend?)
>
> Hast du einen Partner? (Do you have a partner?)

Please note that all these suggestions are informal, so you should not ask someone like your teacher, boss or an older person in this way.

Comment: "Hast du einen Partner?" is not gender neutral! A gender neutral expression would be "Bist du vergeben?"

Comment: @Iris, man kann sich darüber streiten, wie geschlechtsneutral "Partner" ist, aber dafür macht "vergeben" die Frau zu etwas, das man beanspruchen kann.

Comment: @CarstenS _Partner_ ist jedenfalls nicht geschlechtsneutraler als _Freund_ – außerdem nicht idiomatisch.

Comment: "Bist du liiert" ist absolut geschlechtsneutral ;)

Comment: @Carsten S, Männer kann man auch fragen, ob sie vergeben sind.

Comment: Im Ursprungstext der Antwort stand: _**more** gender neutral_ nicht _**absolutely** gender neutral_. Aufgrund der Möglichkeit "Partner" auch unabgeändert für weibliche Personen zu nutzen, sah ich das als gerechtfertigt an. Es ist nicht die Absicht, hier eine Gender-debatte zu starten. @Crissov ich schätze deinen Input, wäre dir dennoch verbunden, wenn du es mir überließest, problematische Stellen aus meinen Antworten zu streichen.